# horizontal scroll - like github

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a javascript library which lets me do the horizontal scrolls effect kind like github does when you click on a file/folder.

Preferrably jQuery plugin.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source for github, it seems they use [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to slide the content to the left.

```
$("#id").animate({
    marginLeft: "-1200px"
});
```

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfYKJ/)

Answer (score 2):

For a more in-depth answer, GitHub actually wrote about how they've assembled their directory structure [on their blog](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider).

But yes they're using jQuery for the actual effects themselves. They mention using slideTo() in that post, but in the end it's really just an [$.animate() effect](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to look into [jQuery.ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/), a jQuery plugin really usefull for this kind of effects.

You could have like github a div with a `overflow:hidden` containing your slides or pages and above the same kind of links than in the jQuery.ScrollTo example page.